# Should there not be/is there a 'tag not relevent' flag option

Tags: support, feature-request, tags, questions

I'm sick of searching through the questions for a particular tag (e.g. php) and seeing questions that are tagged with it, but are not relevant to php what-so-ever, people seem to think just because their example code features php then it is a relevant tag, but it brings nothing new to the question and potential answerers of php questions could go on this question and questions like this simply because of the tag, and then are unduly annoyed that they can't help

Plus it really is bad for the questioner because it will attract the wrong type of audience.

this is a good example: [How do I add my css styles and images to my dynamic wordpress menu correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26489027/how-do-i-add-my-css-styles-and-images-to-my-dynamic-wordpress-menu-correctly)

^ it references php as a tag but is mainly about css

at the moment you can obviously suggest the edit of tag removal, but this is dependent on user review, when really, a moderator should have the power to just put the question on hold because of the mistake, it really is wasting peoples time when they have to filter through rubbish to get to questions they can answer.

(I am sorry if there is support for this kind of error, I just wish to know so I can then use it!)

Comment: You can edit the tag out, as you are aware. Once you reach 2K rep you can do this without being reviewed. There's no need to close questions just because someone included a tag, if they are beginners they might not know it's not relevant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have more than 2,000 rep you can just edit out the tag.

If you have less than 2,000 rep you can suggest an edit that removes the tag.

There's no need for a flag.

Moderators are here to do the stuff you *can't*.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that (like I said in the question it was possible that there already is a feature to address this problem)

Comment: Also, if you do suggest an edit to remove a tag it can be helpful to include a good explanation as to why.  It will make it more likely for reviewers to approve the change.

Answer (score 1):

> a moderator should have the power to just put the question on hold because of the mistake

Moderators have enough to do as it is. Moderators should get involved when the community cannot take care of the situation. That a tag was misapplied is a trivial mistake and can trivially be fixed by editing the question. And if the only problem with a question is a misapplied tag, putting it on hold is not appropriate.

Comment: I disagree with it being a 'trivial' mistake, it is fundamentally damaging to the site, if a question gets attention from the wrong people it will never be answered to the full extent and with the full expertise it could be, therefore making the point of S.O. null.